# CUDA threads are executed in the same order they start

Tags: cuda

Is it normal, that CUDA parallel blocks are executed from start to finish everytime? I mean:

If I have 3 threads, I always get this:

• First thread finishes.
• Second thread finishes.
• Third thread finishes.

I wonder if this is a normal behaviour cause I am new in CUDA. I know that Open MP, C++ Threads or Java Threads usually give different results everytime. But in CUDA I always get the same order. Is that possible? Or that means that something doesn't work well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee provided by CUDA of this behavior.

Since 32 threads are grouped into a [warp](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simt-architecture), you may observe typical or repeatable behavior there, but if you launch 3 million threads, you'll observe varying order from run to run.

Comment: Well I actually have 10 threads, and have run them for about 100 times and always get the same result. from 1 to 10. Is this still could happen when everything works fine? :)

Comment: Yes.  Warps are groups of 32 threads that are executed in lockstep (you may want to read the warp link to the documentation I provided in my answer).  So their behavior is likely to be more predictable.  You may not even see much variance if you launch 64 threads.  But if you launch 3 million threads, you will see variance in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If those threads are in the same warp, they will executed in lockstep where the order is determined by hardware, which is very likely from 0 to 31.

If those threads are in different warp but in the same thread block, the order determined by a warp scheduler will be unpredictable.

If those threads are in different thread blocks, the order determined by a block scheduler will be unpredictable.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow check whether threads are in the same warp? I tested it out, and can guarantee that they are at the same block which number is 0. I also wonder if it is possible to force threads to be executed in different blocks, that I can get a randomized order?

Comment: @user3111627 For your first question, threads satisfying (the thread ID % 32) are same are in the same warp. For the second question, when you launch the kernel, just make the block number more than 1 and each block only consists of 1 thread. In that way, you can get a random order. You can make it clear if you well understand the concepts of warps, blocks, and multiprocessors.

Comment: You indeed need to understand the concepts of warps/block/SM's. Threads in a given block are grouped into "warps" of 32 threads (so far it's always 32; might change in the future ?) that executes in lock-step, i.e. they all do instruction 0, then 1, then 2, etc. You don't really have other guarantees that that ; in particular, I don't think there's any guarantees for the order of the warps within a block.

Comment: @RobertCrovella right, it is not guaranteed by CUDA.